# How to set related_name in ManyToMany field in an abstract model?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I have this abstract model:

```
class HasSystemMessage(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    messages = models.ManyToManyField(SystemMessage, related_name=?)
```

I am going to use this abstract model in at least three other models, lets say, A, B, and C. How can I set the related_name dynamically for these classes? for example, for class B, I want the related_name to be Bs. Is it possible to do so?

To further clarify the question, The classes will look like this:

```
class B(HasSystemMessage):
    # Some model fields 
class A(HasSystemMessage):
    # Some model fields

HasSystemMessage.objects.filter(a__contains=[some elements])
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `%(class)s` or `%(app_label)s`

```
class HasSystemMessage(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    messages = models.ManyToManyField(SystemMessage, related_name=%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related)
```

From Django docs

> Be careful with related_name and related_query_name¶ If you are using
>   related_name or related_query_name on a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField,
>   you must always specify a unique reverse name and query name for the
>   field. This would normally cause a problem in abstract base classes,
>   since the fields on this class are included into each of the child
>   classes, with exactly the same values for the attributes (including
>   related_name and related_query_name) each time.
>
> To work around this problem, when you are using related_name or
>   related_query_name in an abstract base class (only), part of the value
>   should contain '%(app_label)s' and '%(class)s'.
>
> '%(class)s' is replaced by the lower-cased name of the child class
>   that the field is used in. '%(app_label)s' is replaced by the
>   lower-cased name of the app the child class is contained within. Each
>   installed application name must be unique and the model class names
>   within each app must also be unique, therefore the resulting name will
>   end up being different.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name

Comment: These arguments return the class name, not the parent class name. for example, if I have class B which inherits this class, I want the related name field to be B

Comment: This argument(`%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related`) will return `app_name_a_related` for `class A` and similarly for `class B` it will be `app_name_b_related`. So for you case the releaded name in `class B` will be `B` if you use only `%(.class)s` as relaswd name

Comment: @raziehbabaee Hope this was your initial query. If not can explain further what you need.

Comment: @raziehbabaee if you want to get the parent class name `HasSystemMessage` from chile class `class B` you could use `self.__class__.__bases__` this will contain a list of base classes for that `base.__name__` will give the parent class's name.

Comment: @raziehbabaee But if you use the parent class name for related names won't it be same for all the child classes A, B, C?

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to put a string in this attribute which specifies the name of the reverse relation from the `SystemMessage`.[Also read in Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

**Try this:**

```
class HasSystemMessage(models.Model):
class Meta:
    abstract = True

messages = models.ManyToManyField(SystemMessage, related_name='system_message')
```

Comment: actually I want different related names for different parent classes.

Comment: Did you try naming them differently? if yes, is there any error?

Comment: I know how I should set the related_name, I just don't know how to make it more dynamic for abstract models.